# Всплывающая подсказка, использую php код для интернет магазина

Tags: php, wordpress

Знания в php у меня не большие. Моя задача : при наведении курсора на товар - всплывает подсказка ( с весом, ценой и составом товара). Я использую плагин WooCommerce и такой функции в нём нету. Единственное решение - дописывать в content-product вывод характеристик товара плюс оформление это всё на хаверах в css.
Если кто-то сталкивался с таким - я бы очень хотел получить консу

Answer (score 0):

1) делаешь блок  на карточке товара, пишешь стили , чтоб показывался при наведении, или как тебе нужно.
2) потом идешь в функцию которая отвечает за отработку карточки товара. 
рекомендую дописать 1 переменную, которая будет собираться http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php  .